# ng-grid overriding default value with placeholder

Tags: ng-grid

I have a dataset that I summarize using `ng-grid`. Some of the data contains default values `-10` that capture the state for that variable.

Instead of showing `-10` in the cell, I'd like the input cell to display "Enter Value". I tried accomplishing this with "placeholder", but this only inserts a value when there is no underlying data.

```
$scope.myData = [
  {id:"First", value:-10},
  {id:"Second", value:10},
  {id:"Third", value:-10},
  {id:"Fourth", value:10},
  {id:"Fifth", value:-10}];

$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  columnDefs: [{field: 'id', displayName: 'ID'}, 
               {field: 'value', displayName: 'Value', cellTemplate : '<div><input type="text" placeholder="Enter value" ng-model="row.entity.value"/></div>'},
               ]};
```